# Search and replace text in sql server

Tags: sql-server, regex

i've the following pattern on each line

```
21,N                                        
54,N           
34,N         
.  
.   
.  
.
```

and so on

i wanted to replace the above so that they are as below

```
21,  
54,  
34,  
.  
.  
.
```

i tried to search the text using regular expression like [0-9][0-9],N
and it works fine
when i try to replace the above as [0-9][0-9],
it doesnt seem to work. i get something like the below instead

```
[0-9][0-9],  
[0-9][0-9],  
[0-9][0-9],  
.  
.  
.  
.
```

can someone please help out and let me know how i can achieve the desired result

Comment: Just replace `,N` with `,`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there are other places where ',N' is present and is legitimate. if i use the above then that will also get replaced. Hence i was tyring to search by pattern and then replace

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableName 
 set FieldName = Left(FieldName,len(fieldName)-1) 
WHERE fieldName like '%,N'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not data in a table which i need to replace. these are part of insert statements which i need to replace before running them through. could you please let me know how i can do that.

Comment: Why does it have to be done prior to the insert?  If the insert is in a transaction and this statement is executed after the insert will it not achieve the desired results?  If the data isn't in  a table why is sql-server listed as a Tag?  But I digress.... Where is the data and what tools do we have to alter it?  C# VB?, Excel? or are you wanting to cleanse the data on the insert?